# Nginx passing parameters to a PHP file

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi

I'm trying to **pass all the requests** that hits a specific **location**, to a `PHP` file **with the request URL** via Nginx config file, I've almost done this but I cannot pass the URL to the PHP file.

I've tried `var_dump($_REQUEST); var_dump($_ENV); var_dump($argv);` but returns NULL or emtpy array results.

```
location /p/ {

     try_files $uri $uri/ @php;         
}

location @php {
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /var/process/internal/t.php; # this script catches all requests
        fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING $uri;
        include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to move the `include fastcgi_params;` higher, above the `fastcgi_param`s